# How can I detect a div resize?

Tags: jquery, resize, listener

I have a map canvas that I need to check when it gets resized. The default `min-height` is 200px.

The way it gets resized is that I click a button and an extra class is added to the div. This extra class changes the value of `min-height` to 350px.

I've not been successful in adding an listener on the div. So the only solution that is working at the moment is the `.on('click)` event on the button.

```
    $('#resize').on('click', function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }, 500);
    });
```

I've tried the following solutions without success:

```
    // Attemt 1
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 'resize', function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });

    // Attemt 2
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });

    // Attemt 3
    $(window).resize(function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
```

You can see my [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d7fykbzm/9/).

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

A div does not trigger resize, so you cannot listen for that event to happen and then execute your code. What you can however do is the following, I've tested it and it works.

```
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        $('#map-canvas').trigger($.Event('resize'));
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });

    $('#map-canvas').bind('resize', function(){
        $('#map-canvas').toggleClass('resize'); 
    });
```

Triggering a 'resize' event and then binding to it works.

Comment: The whole point is having a listener on the the `resize` event/action of a div so that I don't have to use `$('#resize').on('click', function()...`

Comment: No, because I'm not changing the window, just a DOM element inside the window. Open the JS fiddle and test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer the question but there is some useful discussion of different ways of doing this and links to implementations in this post on the Chrome developers forum, which was about removal of the non-standard "overflowchanged" that used to provide one solution to this: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/1RCzsyEyNU8/5vNpxrhRbUIJ